# How can i get the command which executes when you click an npc?

Tags: java, minecraft, spigot

I`m tried to get the command which executes when i click an npc on my server. How can i get this command?

I tried to use some modded client to get it but it didnt helped.

Comment: No command is run when clicking on NPC, only some event but they depend of the platform

Answer (score 0):

There is not a direct event for that, but you can use "PlayerInteractEntity" and compare if the clicked entity is a Villager or whatever NPC you want.

Something like this:

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerInteractEntity(PlayerInteractEntityEvent e) {
    Entity ent = e.getRightClicked();
    
    if (ent instanceof NPC){
    // Do whatever
    }
}
```